# Find a result using recursion query {inner join}

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have a table like :

```
To_FRIEND | FROM_FRIEND      | FOR_FRIND
1         | 2                |3
1         | 5                |2 
1         | 9                |5
```

I need inner or recursion query to give me the related friends of Friend No **1**

like

```
FRIENDS RELATED 
2   
3     
5
9
```

[image: explination]

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select from_friend
from t
where to_friend = 1
union
select for_friend
from t
where to_friend = 1;
```

It returns what you want, but recursion doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
select [from-friend]
from [dbo].[stk-stuff]
where [to-friend] = 1
union
select [for-friend]
from [dbo].[stk-stuff]
where  [to-friend]= 1
) 

select * from cte
```

Comment: is with    an olap function